# How to extract the content of a paragraph in a webpage containing specific words like bad, not worthy

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to make a small web crawler which can able to pick the negative reviews of a product in a web page. I have developed a code which can able to search the web page with particular set of words and return whether that words are present or not in the web page. But i need to pick the entire review content which contain this words. I am using jsoup to get the content of the page. I am providing the my code below please suggest me how to retrieve this entire data of a particular review and how can i generalize this to apply on any web page to get negative comments data.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.*;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class JsoupWordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        List<String> contain = new ArrayList<String>();

        contain.add("bad");
        contain.add("horrible");
        contain.add("not satisfied");

        System.out.println("Downloading page...");
        Document doc = Jsoup
                .connect("http://www.amazon.in/Moto-Plus-4th-Gen-Black/product-reviews/B01DDP7GZK/ref=dpx_acr_txt?showViewpoints=1").get();

        // Get the actual text from the page, excluding the HTML
        String text = doc.body().text();

        System.out.println("Analyzing text...");
        // Create BufferedReader so the words can be counted
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] words = line.split("[^A-ZÃƒâ€¦Ãƒâ€žÃƒâ€“a-zÃƒÂ¥ÃƒÂ¤ÃƒÂ¶]+");
            List<String> words1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            words1 = Arrays.asList(words);

            if (contain.removeAll(words1))

            {
                System.out.println("The word is present in the document");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Noooooooo!");
            }
        }

        reader.close();
        time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;

        System.out.println("Finished in " + time + " ms");
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess you forgot to add your code to the question... :-)

Comment: Hi Jones i added my code now... :)